# Is the "four hundred years" the equivalent of the "four generations" in the Gen. 15:13-16 prophecy?

Tags: genesis, contradiction, historical-interpretation, authorial-intent, egypt

Gen. 15:13

> Then the Lord said to him, “Know for certain that for **four hundred
> years** your descendants will be strangers in a country not their own
> and that they will be enslaved and mistreated there.

And then in v. 16

> In the **fourth generation** your descendants will come back here, for the
> sin of the Amorites has not yet reached its full measure.

Is there a connection between the *four hundred years* sojourn in Egypt and the *fourth generation* returning to Canaan? This question has been inspired by this [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30798/fourth-from-whom-in-genesis-1512-16). There Phil suggests a provocative idea that the four generations are actually the equivalent of four hundred years, since in the biblical framework a generation (or more specifically an Abrahmic generation) is thought to be the equivalent of a hundred years. Phil believes that this explains how the four generation prophecy has been fulfilled, while I take issue with it and offer another solution. But then it struck me that it may actually be the other way around, i.e., if Phil is right in suggesting that a generation is a hundred years, then is it possible that the four hundred years is actually modeled after the four generations, i.e., that the four hundred years of Egyptian bondage is another expression of the four-generations-in-bondage prophecy? I'm inclined to think that it's modeled this way and not vice versa, since the fourth generation motif is a common motif in the bible, and can also be found in the [ten commandments](https://biblehub.com/exodus/20-5.htm), so it makes sense that if there is any modeling after, that the four generations prophecy (i.e. that the iniquity of the Amorites has not reached full measure until the fourth generation) would precede the four hundred years prophecy.

This may possibly resolve the age old [Egyptian sojourn chronology problem](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6041/how-long-were-the-children-of-israel-enslaved-in-egypt-according-to-the-bible?noredirect=1&lq=1), since if four hundred years only meant four generations then the fact that it was less than four hundred literal years (but four literal generations) should not pose much of a problem, since the four hundred years were never meant to be taken literally, but as another expression of the four generation prophecy which was indeed fulfilled, see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/calendarstudies/exodus-6-16-20). But I'm getting ahead of myself.

My question is has such a connection ever been explored? Is there evidence to suggest that a generation in the bible is the equivalent of a hundred years, and is it plausible that the four hundred years were understood by the biblical authors as four generations and nothing more?

---

The only problem I can see here is that understood this way, the four generations prophecy would in a way undermine the four hundred years prophecy. Since according to v. 16, the *fourth* generation is already returning to the land, whereas according to v. 13 the Israelites would be in bondage for four hundred years, i.e., four *complete* generations. This problem is actually very similar to the problem I raise with Phil's answer [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/30798/fourth-from-whom-in-genesis-1512-16). There are ways to resolve this (and the problem with Phil's answer), but I'm leaving this question open for now, awaiting the feedback of the community.

Answer (score 1):

The 400 years and the four generations are not the same time periods, but they do fully overlap.  The additional time period which overlaps both the 400 years and the four generations is that of the 430 years referenced in Exodus 12:40-41:

> "Now the sojourning of the children of Israel, who dwelt in Egypt, was
> four hundred and thirty years.  And it came to pass at the end of the
> four hundred and thirty years, even the selfsame day it came to pass,
> that all the hosts of the LORD went out from the land of Egypt."
> (Exodus 12:40-41)

What challenges many people in understanding these passages, ironically, is the definition of "Egypt."  At its zenith, during the times of Abraham, "Egypt" was a vast empire that included the lands of Canaan and Israel as well.  It afterward got smaller, and by the time Jacob took his family to "Egypt", he "entered" a much-reduced territory which still pertained to Egypt--entering from what, in his grandfather's day, had been part of Egypt as well.  In a sense, then, the family, which had already been in Egypt, "re-entered" the land, even though they had never actually left that territory from the time of Abraham onward--its political boundary had simply receded from them.

With that in mind, let's look more closely at the times again.

#### The 400 Years versus the 430 Years

To Abraham had been given the promise:

> And he said unto Abram, Know of a surety that thy seed shall be a
> stranger in a land that is not theirs, and shall serve them; and they
> shall afflict them four hundred years;  And also that nation, whom
> they shall serve, will I judge: and afterward shall they come out with
> great substance.  (Genesis 15:13-14)

When was Abraham given this promise?  He received this promise before he had had any children, so the clock on the four-hundred years' prophecy could not possibly have started yet.  In fact, this was a special promise to Abraham because it confirmed to him that he *would* have a child.

How old was Abraham when he entered "Egypt"?

> Now the LORD had said unto Abram, Get thee out of thy country, and
> from thy kindred, and from thy father's house, unto a land that I will
> show thee:  And I will make of thee a great nation, and I will bless
> thee, and make thy name great; and thou shalt be a blessing: And I
> will bless them that bless thee, and curse him that curseth thee: and
> in thee shall all families of the earth be blessed. So Abram departed,
> as the LORD had spoken unto him; and Lot went with him: **and Abram was
> seventy and five years old when he departed out of Haran.**  (Genesis
> 12:1-4)

It was at that time, when Abram was 75 years old, that, having left Haran, he entered "Canaan", at that time annexed by Egypt.  So the 430 years' reference dates from Abraham's entry into Egypt.

How old was Abraham when he had a son?

> "And Abraham was an hundred years old, when his son Isaac was born
> unto him." (Genesis 21:5)

So, his "seed" (Isaac) was born to him 25 years after his entry into "Egypt".  But when did the affliction or bondage begin?  It did not begin yet when Isaac was too young to be exposed to anyone much beyond his mother's arms.  But when Isaac was five years old, a weaning party was held for him:

> "And the child grew, and was weaned: and Abraham made a great feast
> the same day that Isaac was weaned.  And Sarah saw the son of Hagar
> the Egyptian, which she had born unto Abraham, mocking.  Wherefore she
> said unto Abraham, Cast out this bondwoman and her son: for the son of
> this bondwoman shall not be heir with my son, even with Isaac."
> (Genesis 21:8-10)

Notice that Isaac was bullied by "the son of Hagar **the Egyptian**."  As Abram had been sojourning in Egypt, the hired maid whom Sarai had given him for the role of surrogate mother, had been Egyptian.  And it was at this point that the prophecy's 400 years began, for at this point the "affliction" part had begun.  The years of "bondage" were yet future.

#### The Four Generations

> "And God spake unto Israel in the visions of the night, and said,
> Jacob, Jacob. And he said, Here am I.  And he said, I am God, the
> God of thy father: fear not to go down into Egypt; for I will there
> make of thee a great nation:  I will go down with thee into Egypt; and
> I will also surely bring thee up again: and Joseph shall put his hand
> upon thine eyes."  (Genesis 46:2-4)

During the famine, when Jacob, at Joseph's special invitation, had brought all of his family into "Egypt," the count began on the four generations.  We can see those generations recorded in the Bible.  While all of Jacob's sons are mentioned, we'll follow the line of Levi:

> "And these are the names of the children of Israel, which came into
> Egypt, Jacob and his sons: Reuben, Jacob's firstborn.  . . . And the
> sons of Levi; Gershon, Kohath, and Merari."  (Genesis 46:8,11)

> "And these are the names of the sons of Levi according to their
> generations; Gershon, and Kohath, and Merari: and the years of the
> life of Levi were an hundred thirty and seven years. . . . And the
> sons of Kohath; Amram, and Izhar, and Hebron, and Uzziel: and the
> years of the life of Kohath were an hundred thirty and three years.
> . . . And Amram took him Jochebed his father's sister to wife; and she
> bare him Aaron and Moses: and the years of the life of Amram were an
> hundred and thirty and seven years.  . . . These are that Aaron and
> Moses, to whom the LORD said, Bring out the children of Israel from
> the land of Egypt according to their armies.  These are they which
> spake to Pharaoh king of Egypt, to bring out the children of Israel
> from Egypt: these are that Moses and Aaron." (Exodus 6:16, 18, 20,
> 26-27)

> And Moses was content to dwell with the man: and he gave Moses
> Zipporah his daughter.  And she bare him a son, and he called his name
> Gershom: for he said, I have been a stranger in a strange land.
> (Exodus 2:21-22)

Summarizing those verses we have:

```
Jacob   --> The patriarch who brought his children and 
            grandchildren to "enter" (re-enter) Egypt;
Levi    --> Entered Egypt, Jacob's son;
Kohath  --> Entered Egypt, the first generation,
            Levi's son;
Amram   --> The second generation, Kohath's son; and
Moses   --> The third generation, Amram's son, 
            who led the Israelites back out of Egypt.
Gershom --> The fourth generation, Moses' son,
            representing the generation brought out of Egypt.
```

The total time from entry into Egypt to departure in the fourth generation may have been around 215 years--half of the 430-year total from Abraham's first entry to the exodus.  But the time for actual hard bondage (slavery) would have been closer to 90 years--just under a century.  We know that Moses was 80 years old at the time he led the people out of Egypt, and the Israelites had been in bondage during Moses' entire lifetime at that point, plus a few years before he was born.

Remember, it was not until after the time of Joseph (after the second generation, post-entry), that the slavery had begun--by an Egyptian king who had not known Joseph.  In other words, the slavery began during the third generation, post-entry, and ended when the fourth generation departed in the Exodus.

[image: Timeline of 400-Year Prophecy and Four Generations]

Comment: I'm not really sure how you addressed my question. In any case, your assumption that the 400 year prophecy starts from Abram is highly speculative and contested (and I think is false) See for example this link https://sites.google.com/site/calendarstudies/exodus-6-16-20 where the author explains and proves that the 400 most probably started from the time Levi first went down to Egypt (which really makes sense, since the sojourn of the Israelites in Egypt continued non-stop since Levi entered Egypt, as opposed to Abram which had Isaac and Jacob that were all over Canaan and Mesopotamia).

Comment: @Bach Time prophecies are useless if they do not specify their endpoints.  A 400-year prophecy with no definite time to start is not really a 400-year prophecy anymore--it's just a vagueness.  But the prophecy specifies its start point.  It must begin with Abram's seed being either in affliction or in bondage.  As the affliction came first, that's where it starts, and the clock is then ticking toward its finish, which must not exceed 400 years in total.  Isaac was first afflicted by an Egyptian at his weaning party--the Bible makes this clear.

Comment: @Bach In reading some from that site I've realized a mistake I'd made in the genealogy.  It is true that Jacob entered Egypt, but it is also true that Levi entered Egypt with him.  So the reckoning should start, not with Jacob, but with his sons as the first generation.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Bach  The answer shows that the four generations are part of the 400 years.  This isn't some sermon of mine, this is simply the Bible truth.  I've done my best to make it clear.  If you don't like the answer, downvote it even if you wish, but because you don't find it helpful, you think I should delete it?  Perhaps others will appreciate it.  The site is not only for your benefit, nor was I writing the answer for any specific person.  I'm a bit surprised, actually, after having taken the time to make the timeline graphic and add it here, to receive such a reprimand for it. Totally unexpected.

Comment: Polyhat, but you seem to miss the point of this question. I'm not asking how much generations we can cram into 400 years? My question is if the 400 years is another expression of the four generation prophecy. In order to answer this effectively you would have to either show proof that a generation generally equals hundred years in the bible, or prove from the text itself in Gen. 15 that this is what is intended, or reject my hypothesis altogether (on solid grounds).

Comment: But your post seems to address something else entirely: how many Israelite generations were in Egypt, and how many years elapsed from the time of entry until the Exodus. Granted, all these topics are somewhat related to my question, but it's not formulated as an answer to my question, just a ramble of many different indirect points about the Exodus, which again are important but not directly addressing my question (usually when I post an answer I summarize in the end how I think I have answered the OP's question).

Comment: I do not mean to offend you, on the contrary, I appreciate when ppl like you take their time to address other user's questions, but some users here on BH see someone else's question as a way to post their own sermons which frustrates me to no end. I'm not accusing you of this behavior, but look for example at this question, it has garnered 5 answers so far, and none remotely address the question that was asked.

Comment: @Bach  I could state the answer to your question in a single paragraph. But would you understand and accept it?  The complexity of the details to support the answer required more explanation--and it appears I have not explained it _enough_.  Here's a one-sentence attempt:  The four hundred years and the four generations are separate prophecies with separate, albeit overlapping, fulfillments in which the four generations amount to about a quarter of the 400 years.  Note that the Bible does not give the exact number of years for the four generations; only approximations can be ascertained.

Comment: @Bach Biblical chronology has been an interest of mine since I was in gradeschool, and I have very carefully calculated the times that I post in my answer--none of this is copy/paste from some other source.  As such, I am able to answer questions and to support the details of my answer from the Bible, without assistance from commentaries (which are often imprecise when it comes to chronology). If, therefore, you have a question about one of the specifics, feel free to ask. As it stands, you seem to want only to know that "No, the 400 years are not the same as the 4 generations." Is that right?

Comment: Poly if that's your stance then yes (that would be your short answer), but you would still have to bring solid proof that this is not the case, and why you think my hypothesis is untenable. Then if you will, you can go on to explain how you long you think the Egyptian bondage was, and how many generations were there (perhaps as an appendix). But the main thing is that your answer stays focused. I would even upvote such answer, even if I find myself disagreeing with your conclusions.

Comment: I think this is a really good answer. I'd point out that Canaan had yet to be conquered by the Israelites - to clarify the constant strangerdom.

Answer (score 0):

Let us remind ourselves of some of the chronology of the history from Abraham to Moses:

- Abraham moves from Haran to Canaan at age 75, Gen 12:4
- Isaac born to Abraham at the age of 100, Gen 21:5
- Isaac marries Rebekah at age 40, Gen 25:20
- Isaac becomes the father of Jacob at age 60, Gen 25:26
- Jacob (at age 71) deceives Isaac when he is 131, Gen 47:9, 45:6, 41:47
- Jacob returns from Padam Aram after 20 years at age 91, as Joseph is born, Isaac 151.
- Joseph is sold into slavery at age 17 (Gen 37:2), Jacob is 108, Isaac is 168.
- Isaac dies at age 180, Gen 35:28.
- Jacob moves to Egypt at age 130, Gen 47:9 during the second year of famine when Joseph is 39 years old.
- Jacob dies at age 147, Gen 47:28

Thus, there were 215 years between Abraham's promise in Gen 12 and Jacob moving to Egypt.  There were 430 years between Jacob moving to Egypt and the Exodus, Ex 12:40, 41, Gal 3:17.

Further there were more than four generation between Abraham and Moses:

- Abraham was the father of Isaac
- Isaac was the father of Jacob
- Jacob was the father of Levi and his 12 borthers including Joseph
- Levi was the father of Gershom and Kohath (Ex 6:16)
- Gershom was the father of Amram who married Jochebed (Ex 6:18, 20)
- Amram was the father of Moses and Aaron (Ex 6:20)
- Moses was the father of Gershom, Ex 2:22

Thus, there were four generation between Abraham and the entry to Egypt: Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, Levi and the 12 brothers.

There were also four generations that lived in Egypt before the Exodus: Levi, Gershom, Amram, Moses.

The prophecy of 400 years (a round number that is not exact) in Gen 15 was made a few decades after Abraham had moved to Canaan (and been to Egypt) Gen 12.  The four generation of Gen 15 is clearly the four generations that lived in Egypt for 215 years before the Exodus.

By this calculation, each generation lasted about 50 years - Moses was in his 70s when his first son was born and 80s when his second son was born.  Other generations were not as old.  Joseph had his two sons in his 30s.

Comment: So are you rejecting my hypothesis based on a dubious tradition that the Israelites were in Egypt for only 215 years (although the bible clearly states otherwise)?

Comment: @Bach - I base my conclusions, not upon any "dubious traditions" (which I have not referenced), but the explicit testimony and chronology of the Bible as documented above.   Further, I am unaware of such a tradition, so I cannot reference it.

Comment: If youre looking for a reliable resource, see this https://sites.google.com/site/calendarstudies/exodus-6-16-20. It also explains how the 400 year sojourn in Egypt is supposed to be reckoned according to the biblical authors themselves!

Comment: Actually I looked at your answer and you have the 215 years before the Exodus, which is kind of baffling, since the famous Jewish tradition of 215 years (which your entire answer is really based on, although you may not be aware of it) is the time period of the Egyptian bondage itself, but you have it the other way around. I find it hard to agree with anything in your post.

Comment: @Bach - that is fine.  I just read the Bible as it is and quote it as I find as documented in the answer.